# Why realloc with size '0' allows to free the pointer multiple times but not malloc with size '0'?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following code.

```
char *ptr2 = (char*)malloc(0);
char *ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
memcpy(ptr, "Gunasek\0", 8);
ptr = (char*) realloc(ptr, 0);
printf("ptr = %p, ptr2 = %p\n", ptr, ptr2);
//ptr = (nil), ptr2 = 0x602420       (Output)
free(ptr);
free(ptr);//Works fine
free(ptr);//Works fine

free(ptr2);
free(ptr2);//Fails
free(ptr2);
```

Could anyone explain why **malloc(0)** doesn't allow for free more than once but **realloc(ptr, 0)** does?

Comment: Freeing .a `NULL` pointer does no harm. `malloc (0)` is *Undefined Behavior*. .You can `realloc` with *Size* `0`.

Comment: `malloc` of size 0 is implementation defined behaviour, not undefined.

Comment: Theoretically the allocation manager is the same for both, meaning in one way or another,  `realloc()` uses `malloc()` internally. The reason `free()` fails is probably not related to what function you used to allocate, but simply undefined behavior showing it's ugly mug. Also have you considered that `realloc()` with size 0 simply returns `NULL`?

Comment: @Havenard, okay. I thought **undefined behaviour** is, it may or may not work sometimes. Didn't expect that it will work all the times (like the **free(ptr)** do)

Comment: At least at [ideone](https://ideone.com/8TcTLs), `realloc()` with size 0 returns `NULL`. `free(NULL)` does nothing. You're not doing proper testing, not to mention zero-length allocation doesn't exist. That `malloc(0)` is probably allocating 1 byte or something.

Comment: @Havenard, **mallloc(0)** won't allocate any byte. Memory manager will store only the metadata related to that (as far as I know). I will do few more experiments and come back.

Comment: @GunasekaranSrinivasan I read somewhere that it's defined behavior, `malloc()` should it succeed must allocate at least 1 byte, Citation needed.

Comment: @GunasekaranSrinivasan Perhaps it's implementation defined, the standard only mentions it should return either null or a unique pointer that is valid to pass to `free()`. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html

Comment: @Havenard, okay fine. In this case, Is it returning unique pointer and free that pointer is undefined behavior? And **realloc(ptr, 0)** return null pointer and **free(NULL)**  any number of times is valid?

Comment: @GunasekaranSrinivasan, that certain behavior is undefined says nothing about variability of behavior.  That would be a partial definition.  "Undefined behavior" means *the standard* does not support any prediction at all about the behavior, including any side effects it may have.

Comment: @GunasekaranSrinivasan It's `NULL` so `free()` ignores it. A valid pointer howover will be freed, but you are only supposed to free it once.

Comment: @GunasekaranSrinivasan, furthermore, there is an enormous difference between "it did not crash with a segfault" and "it worked".  In particular, you have to consider the universe of possible side effects that may arise from exercising undefined behavior, but that may not be immediately evident.

Comment: @Havenard, yeah that's what I meant for the unique pointer returned by **malloc(0)**. Can you write you explanation as an answer and I will accept it so that it'll be useful for others?

Comment: I honestly don't see how that is useful, if we are going to document here every possible case of undefined behavior, Stack Exchange is going to need bigger servers.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I am new to the **standard recommendation** and implementation details which might vary from compiler to compilers. Thank you for inputs.

Comment: @Havenard, okay fine. At least I have got some idea on this. Thank you.

Comment: @GunasekaranSrinivasan please [edit]  your question and add `printf("ptr = %p, ptr2 = %p\n", ptr, ptr2);` before the first `free` and show us the output. This will make your question more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Freeing a non-null pointer more than once is undefined behaviour (whether it came from `malloc` or `realloc`).  Understanding why your particular implementation behaves the way it does is therefore unhelpful.  It would also be dangerous to rely on this behaviour since it could change in the future or even in a different context.

Comment: Freeing a pointer to an object more than once is not defined by the C standard. Freeing a null pointer more than once is defined. Since OP’s `realloc` implementation may be returning a null pointer, this is relevant. The behavior OP observes is explainable, and this answer fails to explain it.

Comment: Both `malloc` and `realloc` are permitted to return `NULL` when called with size 0, that's true.  Since the OP didn't mention which compiler he's using, I can't be certain what they will do in his case.  Since he claims that freeing the result of `malloc(0)` "doesn't work", I assumed it's returning a non-null pointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I understand your point. And I guess that's what is happening.

Comment: @PeterRuderman, I am using gcc 5.4 on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Sorry about that